# Property 'download' does not exist on type 'Transfer'. in ionic 2 FileTransfer

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 file transfer native plugin in my app to download Sample.csv file from the server.

Facing below error message:

Property 'download' does not exist on type 'Transfer'.

```
  const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
  let url = 'url to the server file';   
  console.log(url);

  fileTransfer.download(url, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'Sample.csv').then((entry) => {

      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
   }, (error) => {
                    console.log("No file to download");
   });
```

And in console getting Cordova is not defined.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import this.

```
import { Transfer, FileUploadOptions, TransferObject } from '@ionic-native/transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
```

After that inject it like this.

```
constructor(private transfer: Transfer, private file: File) { }
```

Declare it as below.

```
const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();
```

Use like this.

```
// Download a file:
fileTransfer.download(..).then(..).catch(..);
```

You can refer [**official doc here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/).

Comment: thank you,  Property 'download' does not exist on type 'Transfer'. issue has been fixed now, but still getting error message in console that              cordova not defined.

Comment: You cannot run Cordova plugin on the browser.You have to use either device or emulator.

Comment: I tried 'my app' by uploading to the ionic-view app its no file getting downloaded.  when i click on download button nothing happens.

Comment: Ionic view app has a lot of issues with the native plugins.You must use an emulator or actual device.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS so i am not getting how to run this app on emulator. Can you help me out with this. how to do it ?

Comment: You can refer this doc.If you need more help please let me know.http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/cli/run.html